# How can I tell if a Grails/GORM domain instance has been deleted in the current tx (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am looking for a "isDeleted()" test for Grails (GORM) instances:

```
Project p = ... get persistent entity from somewhere ...
p.delete() // done in some nested logic
... sometime later in the code prior to commit of the tx ...
if (!p.isDeleted()) ... do some more stuff ...
```

In my app the logic that may delete p is elsewhere and passing a flag back or something would be a pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get to the Hibernate session and persistence context:

```
import org.hibernate.engine.Status

boolean deleted = Project.withSession { session ->
   session.persistenceContext.getEntry(p).status == Status.DELETED
}
```

Comment: I don't see a getPersistenceContext() on org.hibernate.Session?

Comment: It's in the `org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor` interface that `org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl` implements.

Comment: I ended up using `boolean deleted = Project.withSession { session ->
                    session.persistenceContext.getEntry(p)?.status in [null, Status.DELETED]
                }` as the entity wasn't present in the session for me - maybe as it had been deleted using flush: true.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GORM events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) to automatically set a property within the object once it has been deleted, e.g.

```
class Project{
   String name
   Boolean isDeleted = false
   static transients = [ "isDeleted" ]

  def afterDelete() { 
   isDeleted = true
  }
}
```

If for some reason you don't want to modify the domain classes, you could just use the `exists` method:

```
if (Project.exists(p.id)) {
  // do something....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my thoughts:

```
Project p = ... 
def id = p.id
p.delete(flush:true)
...
if (p.read(id)) //... do some more stuff ...
```

Comment: Hmm. I get a org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException nested inside a HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException when I try this with get/read. I am using Grails 2.0RC1 so maybe its a bug.